# Compass not importing extensions in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

I'm trying to import a compass extension in my current sass file.

```
# /app/assets/stylesheets/application/base.css.sass
@import "compass/css3/border-radius"
```

Problem is that I'm getting the following error when refreshing the page.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 161ms

ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/border-radius.
Load path:     Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/user/Sites/site/app/assets/stylesheets/application/base.css.sass)
  (in /Users/user/Sites/site/app/assets/stylesheets/application/base.css.sass)):
```

For some reason is its not getting the path to compass extensions. In Gemfile I have

```
gem 'compass'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'haml-rails'
```

Comment: what is the absolute path to the border-radius file?

Comment: how can I get that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm a few things:

1) I believe compass-rails is the most up to date compass gem, try this in your gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  # other gems like uglifier and coffee go here as well
end
```

2) I'm using rounded corners in my project and have no trouble, if the above doesn't fix it, try importing all of the css3 mixins.

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Any luck with those?